# Why does using .latest() on an empty Django queryset return...nothing?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here's some code that builds a queryset, and prints the output at each step (for debugging):

```
qs = self.get_queryset(True)
print(qs)  #   [<MyModel: obj_1>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_3>]
qs = qs.get_user(user)
print(qs)  # []
qs = qs.completed()
print(qs)  # []
qs = qs.latest('time_completed')
print(qs)  #    <-- What happened?  Why is this blank?
print(qs is None) # False <-- huh??
print("nothing") if not qs else print("something") #   <-- blank?!?! how?!
print(type(qs)) #
```

The last operation `qs.latest('time_completed')` prints blank, the type is blank, the if statement is ignored.  What's going on here?

An example where the result is NOT an empty queryset works fine (note all items are a single user, just coincidence):

```
qs = self.get_queryset(True)
print(qs)  #  [<MyModel: obj_1>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_3>]
qs = qs.get_user(user)
print(qs)  #  [<MyModel: obj_1>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_3>]
qs = qs.completed()
print(qs)  #  [<MyModel: obj_1>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_2>, <MyModel: obj_3>]
qs = qs.latest('time_completed')
print(qs)  #  obj_1
print("nothing") if not qs else print("something") # something
print(type(qs)) # <class 'my_app.models.MyModel'>
```

Comment: As you experienced `.latest()` on an empty queryset returns `None`. So, did you expect something else or what is your actual question?

Comment: What are `qs.get_user` and `qs.completed`? They are not core methods on querysets. Also the code you have posted above is reassigning the `qs` variable to be other things by the time you try to call `qs.latest`. I don't think the code would work at all. You also mention an if statement in your question - I don't see one in the code. Please post a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KlausD. it doesn't return None, if it returned none it should print `None` and it should get caught in the if statement and print "nothing", but it doesn't do either of these.  I WAS expecting None, but didn't get it!

Comment: @solarissmoke `qs.get_user` etc are custom Manager methods, and are working, as you can see from the results. I just added them to show that stuff is working until I get to `qs.latest`

Comment: @KlausD. `print(qs is None) # False`

Comment: Then, please post your model including managers if there are managers attached.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I provided too much information.  Maybe a better question is, when does Python EVER print nothing? zilch, not `None` but actually nothing!  Under what circumstances can the code `print("nothing") if not anything_here else print("something")` NOT print either "nothing" or "something" or give an error?

Comment: Actually, `.latest()` raises `model.DoesNotExist` when used on an empty queryset: "Like get(), earliest() and latest() raise DoesNotExist if there is no object with the given parameters." ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest)) However, you need to provide more context before we can say anything useful. How are you running this code, is it part of a view or do you run it in a shell? The model and custom managers/querysets would help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

> Like get(), earliest() and latest() raise DoesNotExist if there is no object with the given parameters.

`qs.latest('field')` should raise `Model.DoesNotExist` exception whenever `qs` is an empty queryset.

```
In [2]: Entity.objects.none().latest('creation_date')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Check the exception is not swallowed in your view/method.

Answer (score 9):

If you would like it to return None instead of throw an error, you could use `order_by()` and `last()`.

```
qs.order_by('time_completed').last()
```

This will return None if the queryset is empty.